# SSL question TLS response in TCP

Tags: tls

After some careful looking at one .pcap of my network i would like to undestand why a request appears on the communication like

IP [TLS Application Data] Application Data Protocol: http 
   Version TLS: 1.0
   Encrypted Application Data: a44a55a5aa6aablabla

and then the reply from the destination IP is just a simple TCP packet(Protocol TCP no longer wireshark informs that the connection is ... TLS) with the ACK flag nothing more, what could cause such a strange end of the connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**That's not the end of the connection**, it's just an ACK. TLS operates over TCP (and IP), and the TLS records sent as TCP data are acknowledged just like the data on other TCP connections; in some cases this acknowledgement piggybacks on TCP data in the other direction and in some cases it is a packet carrying only ACK and no data. In the ACK-only case wireshark labels it TCP and not the app-level protocol (here TLS) because there is no app-level data (here TLS).

**The way a TLS connection is closed normally** is by sending an alert record of type `close_notify` in at least one direction, followed by a normal TCP close which sends and ACKs FIN in both directions using a variable number and sequence of packets depending on the dynamic state and timing; see any reference on TCP. A TLS connection can also be closed seminormally by just doing TCP close without the alert, or abnormally by doing TCP abort with (at least one) RST.

All alerts after the handshake completes are encrypted, so wireshark only decodes as Encrypted Alert (unless you enable wireshark to decrypt by giving it the server private key for a non-PFS RSA key-exchange connection, or the session key for the specific session). In principle several alerts are possible, but in practice if you see an alert after normal data exchange it's extremely likely to be close_notify.